# Getting exception in assignment of a value to array in android

Tags: java, android, variable-assignment

I am trying to read an Image pixel by pixel and want to save the pixel RGB value in arrays.
but when trying to do so I am getting an exception in the statement
R[i]=redValue;
Someone please suggest what I might doing wrong?

please find the exception stack trace here -

paste.ubuntu.com/6216208

```
public class AnalyzeImage extends Activity  
{   
    int []R;  
    int []G;  
    int []B;  
    int width, height, i=0;  
    int a=1;  
    public int analyzeImagefunc(Bitmap bitmap)
    {            
    try{ 
     width  =  bitmap.getWidth();
     height = bitmap.getHeight();
     i = 0;
     for(int x = 0;x < width;x++)
     {
      for(int y = 0;y < height;y++)
      {
      int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);         
      int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
      int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
      int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
      a=5;
      R[i]=redValue; 
      a=6;
      i++;
       }
      } 
     }

    catch(Exception e)
        {
            //nothing
        }
     return a;
 }  
}
```

Comment: Array is not initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arrays need to be initialzed first before using. You have jsut declared the arrays:

```
int []R;  
int []G;  
int []B;
```

but not initialized them.So if you try to access any array element it will throw null pointer exception. Try to initialized your array like:

```
int []R = new int[10];  
int []G = new int[10];  
int []B = new int[10];
```

You can change the size of arrays as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

int []R;
    int []G;
    int []B;

R, G, B is not initialized any where.

initialize the R

```
 width  =  bitmap.getWidth();
 height = bitmap.getHeight();
 i = 0;
 int size = height * width;
 R = new int[size]; // initialize the size of array R   
 for(int x = 0;x < width;x++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Array need initialization with fix size. so if array's size is not fix then you should go with ArrayList. and also you can cast ArrayList to array if needed for final output.

```
    public class AnalyzeImage extends Activity {
        int[] R;
        int[] G;
        int[] B;
        ArrayList<Integer> R_Lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> G_Lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> B_Lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int width, height, i = 0;
        int a = 1;

        public int analyzeImagefunc(Bitmap bitmap) {
            try {
                width = bitmap.getWidth();
                height = bitmap.getHeight();
                i = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                        a = 5;
//                      R[i] = redValue;
                        R_Lst.add(redValue);
                        B_Lst.add(blueValue);
                        G_Lst.add(greenValue);
                        a = 6;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            R=convertIntegers(R_Lst);
            return a;
        }
        public int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
        {
            int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
            for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
            {
                ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
            }
            return ret;
        }

//      (Note that this will throw a NullPointerException if either integers or any element within it is null.)
```

Comment: want to save the pixel RGB value in arrays. He want to store the RGB values in Array

Answer (score 1):

```
width = bitmap.getWidth();
height = bitmap.getHeight();
int n = width * height;
R = new int[n];  
G = new int[n];  
B = new int[n];
i = 0;
```

By implication, you also require:

```
R[i] = redValue;
G[i] = greenValue;
B[i] = blueValue;
```